# Convert Python dictionary keys following a key-to-key mapping

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

I am in need of a function used to convert the keys of a Python `dict` to something else, according to a keys mapping. So for example let's say I have the mapping:

```
{
    "olk_key_1": "new_key_1",
    "olk_key_2": "new_key_2",
    "olk_key_3": "new_key_3",
}
```

And the `dict`:

```
{
    "old_key_1": 1,
    "old_key_2": 2,
    "old_key_3": 3,
}
```

What I want is:

```
{
    "new_key_1": 1,
    "new_key_2": 2,
    "new_key_3": 3,
}
```

The tricky part about this is that the functions **MUST SUPPORT ANY SORT OF NESTED STRUCTURE**.

That includes:

- `dict`s of `dict`s
- `dict`s of `list`s
- `list`s of `dict`s

I currently have an ugly working function. Anything better looking (feel free to just refactor my code) will be considered as an answer.

```
def map_keys(self, data, mapping):
    """
    This function converts the data dictionary into another one with different keys, as specified by the mapping
    parameter
    :param data: The dictionary to be modified
    :param mapping: The key mapping
    :return: A new dictionary with different keys
    """
    new_data = data.copy()
    if isinstance(new_data, list):
        new_data = {"tmp_key": new_data}
        mapping.update({"tmp_key": "key_tmp"})
    iterate = list(new_data.items())
    for key, value in iterate:
        if isinstance(value, list) and isinstance(value[0], dict):
            new_list = []
            for item in new_data[key]:
                new_list.append(self.map_keys(item, mapping))
            new_data[mapping[key]] = new_list
        else:
            new_data[mapping[key]] = value
        new_data.pop(key)
    if "key_tmp" in new_data:
        new_data = new_data["key_tmp"]
    return new_data
```

**EDIT**

As an example, the function should be able to convert inputs such as (intentionally excessively convoluted):

```
[
    {
        "a": 1,
        "b":[
                {
                    "c": 1,
                    "d": 1
                },
                {
                    "e": 1,
                    "f": 1
                }
            ]
    },
    {
        "g": {
            "h": {
                "i": 1,
            },
            "j": {
                "k": 1  
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48203795/change-keys-of-a-dict-with-a-mapping-dict

Comment: This question might be better suited for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Saw that, but that answer does not consider lists.

Comment: @OcasoProtal indeed. Although I was kinda hoping for a one-liner kinda Python magic I am unaware of :p

Comment: which dictionary needs to be updated? all dictionaries in the nested structure? Or just the top-level dictionary? Which case doesn't this work for: `new_dict = { key_map[key]: val for key, val in old_dict.items() }`

Comment: @VersBersch every dictionary key in the whole input

Comment: So basically - you want to flatten a list of dicts, correct?

Comment: @HenryYik no no. I want to traverse a structure that contains `dict`s inside (let that be a `list` or a `dict` itself) recursively, and change every single dictionary key.

Comment: @GiacomoCasoni It seems you are searching for custom mapping function in `json`, see my answer.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I am testing it right now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `json.load()` with custom `objects_pairs_hook` parameter ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load)):

```
mapping_d = {
    "old_key_1": "new_key_1",
    "old_key_2": "new_key_2",
    "old_key_3": "new_key_3",
}

d = {
    "old_key_1": 1,
    "old_key_2": 2,
    "old_key_3": [
        {"old_key_1": 4},
        {"old_key_2": 5}
    ],
}

import json

def fn(obj):
    rv = dict([(mapping_d.get(n, n), v) for n, v in obj])
    return rv

d = json.loads(json.dumps(d), object_pairs_hook=fn)
from pprint import pprint
pprint(d, width=30)
```

Prints:

```
{'new_key_1': 1,
 'new_key_2': 2,
 'new_key_3': [{'new_key_1': 4},
               {'new_key_2': 5}]}
```